# Constraining class template function to accept a specific POD type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am teaching myself the new concepts feature of C++20 and I hit a snag when I was trying to ensure that the member function that has to be present only accepts specific types. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394556/c-concepts-can-i-have-a-constraint-requiring-a-function-be-present-in-a-clas) which showed me how to ensure any function can be present. Then I wanted to take it a step further by ensuring a function with specific parameters are present. I started by defining that the type `T` must have a function `number()` that returns an int

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept MyRequirement = requires (T t) 
{
    { t.number(int) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

template <typename T>
  requires MyRequirement<T>
struct RequiresBool
{
  T t;
};

struct GoodType
{
    int number(int x) { return x; };
};

int main() 
{
    RequiresBool<GoodType> good_object;
}
```

but gcc gave me the following error:

```
<source>:7:16: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
    7 |     { t.number(int) } -> std::same_as<int>;
      |                ^~~"
```

So I changed it to the following which worked.

```
template <typename T>
concept MyRequirement = requires (T t, int x) 
{
    { t.number(x) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```

However, when I change the function signature in `GoodType` to `int number(double x)`, it still works. Sure, a `double` can be implicitly converted to an `int` and this would also work for normal functions. I could get around this by declaring (but not defining) `int number(double);` in `GoodType` which would give me an error during compilation, but this puts the responsibility on whoever writes the template class to remember to do this.

This works fine with other types, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
concept MyRequirement = requires (T t, std::string x)
{
    { t.number(x) } -> std::same_as<int>; //int number(int x) is now invalid
};
```

but the integers/doubles give me a headache.

Is some way ensure that the type of x in `MyRequirement` HAS to be an integer using C++20 concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compound requirement (`{ expression}`) checks if the expression is well-formed, so implicit type conversions occur. An `int` can be implicitly converted to a `double`, but a `std::string` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`.

You can use the pointer to member in a compound requirement:

```
template <typename T>
concept MyRequirement = requires {
    { &T::number } -> std::same_as<int (T::*)(int)>;
};
```

Comment: Is the & in &T::number required because it refers to function object and you need  to compare it to the function pointer specified in the return type?

Comment: `T::number` [can't be used alone](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id#2). `&T::number` is a pointer to member function, one of the few contexts in which "an id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class" is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not to familiar with concepts yet, so there might be a more idiomatic way. But this felt intuitive to me and works.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept MyRequirement = std::is_same_v<decltype(&T::number), int (T::*)(int)>;
```

This covers both return type and parameter.

If it's not familiar, `int (T::*)(int)` is a pointer-to-member-function with signature `int(int)` belonging to class `T`.
`decltype(&T::number)` gets the type of a pointer to `T`s member `number`.