# C++ concept: Requiring a static variable to be present in a policy class

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, units-of-measurement

I want to constraint the template parameters of a policy class.
That is, when I call `Foo<policy>`, I want the compiler to stop here if the policy class does not fulfill the requirements I want.

### Complete non-working example

To simplify the problem, let's consider just the requirement that the policy class has to declare a static variable that itself fulfill another concept (here, the Acceleration concepts from the [mp-units library](https://github.com/mpusz/units).

```cpp
#include <units/isq/si/si.h>

using units::isq::Acceleration;

// A policy
struct earth
{
    // requirement seems to be fulfilled
    static inline constexpr Acceleration auto gravity = standard_gravity<>;
};

// Let's define a concept because I will need soon to use a set of more than 1 requirements
template <typename T>
concept SphericBody = requires(T)
{
  { T::gravity } -> Acceleration;
};

// The host class that has a constraint of the template argument
template<SphericBody T>
class Foo
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  Foo<earth> // does not compile :'(
}
```

It fails with the following compiler message:

```
‘T::gravity’ does not satisfy return-type-requirement
     { T::gravity } -> units::isq::Acceleration;
```

In the current version of the mp-units library, the Acceleration concept declaration is the following:

```cpp
#include <units/concepts.h>
#include <units/isq/dimensions/length.h>
#include <units/isq/dimensions/time.h>

namespace units::isq {

template<typename Child, Unit U, typename...>
struct dim_acceleration;

template<typename Child, Unit U, DimensionOfT<dim_length> L, DimensionOfT<dim_time> T>
struct dim_acceleration<Child, U, L, T> : derived_dimension<Child, U, exponent<L, 1>, exponent<T, -2>> {};

template<typename T>
concept Acceleration = QuantityOfT<T, dim_acceleration>;

}  // namespace units::isq
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am aware of this related question: [C++ Concepts - Can I have a constraint requiring a function be present in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394556/10360134) but it focuses on non-static member variables.

### Minimal working example

As requested by @HolyBlackCat, I tried my best to come with a minimal working example. The member variable is now a simple integer. Simply adding the requires clause works:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasGravity = requires(T t)
{
  { t.gravity } -> std::same_as<int&>;
};

struct myearth
{
    int gravity;
};

// The host class that has a constraint of the template argument
template<HasGravity T>
class Foo
{};

// using policy_t = Foo<earth> // compiles
```

### Minimal NON working example

In this case, the requirement is exported to a concept, and it does not compile anymore.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsAcceleration = std::same_as<int&>;
};

// Let's define a concept because I will need soon to use a set of more than 1 requirements
template <typename T>
concept HasGravity = requires(T t)
{
  { t.gravity } -> IsAcceleration;
};

// A policy
struct myearth
{
    int gravity;
};

// The host class that has a constraint of the template argument
template<HasGravity T>
class Foo
{};

// using policy_t = Foo<earth> // does not compile
```

Error:

```
note: constraints not satisfied
test.cpp:45:9:   required for the satisfaction of ‘HasGravity<T>’ [with T = myearth]
test.cpp:45:22:   in requirements with ‘T t’ [with T = myearth]
test.cpp:47:7: note: ‘t.gravity’ does not satisfy return-type-requirement
   47 |   { t.gravity } -> IsAcceleration;
```

Comment: How is `Acceleration` defined? Make a [mcve] please.

Comment: Could you replace in `static inline constexpr Acceleration auto gravity` `auto` with the actual type?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added the concept definition from the [mp-unit](https://github.com/mpusz/units) library header file. It is minimal in the sense that I took out everything but the dependency that gives me a problem.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't think I can do that. I think the types are rather complicated. For example, the way they declare it in the documentation is `constexpr Acceleration auto expected = 9.81 * (m / (s*s));` But the type will change according to the measure system.

Comment: What is `QuantityOfT`? We want something that we can actually compile and reproduce the error ourselves. That should be explained in the link.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I understand your frustration, but it's like having a problem with a part of the boost library, right? You still end up having an external dependency that is not the STL in the explanation of your problem?

Comment: Does the same error happen with simpler types and a static variable?

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler An isolated example would still be nice, but I see your point. I think I see what's going on, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you people! @Sebastian I added simpler examples with a integer as a non-static member variable :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library, but my guess is that the `Acceleration` concept rejects references.

`{ expr } -> concept` requirements determine the type as if by `decltype((expr))`, which for your variable yields an lvalue reference.

---

`decltype` inspects the value category of the expression, and adds `&` to types of lvalues and `&&` to types of xvalues (prvalue types are unchanged). Since expressions [can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), this doesn't lose any information.

`decltype` has a special case for variables - for them it returns the type as written, discarding the value category. By adding a second pair of parentheses, you disable this feature, falling back to the behavior described above.

Comment: Thank you! I played around with references and could put together a working  minimal example and a minimal non-working example :)

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler That's easy to do after you know the answer. :P

Comment: Ahahaha true, true ;) But tbh it does not entirely solve my problem, as I still struggle understand why the last example does not work :'(

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler Seems to work after I fixed the typos: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dTKx4d97M

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler You're not using Clang 12, are you? It had a bug where it used `decltype(??)` instead of `decltype((??))` for `{} ->` requirements.

Comment: Oh godbolt is so nice! Well, i'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
` enabled for C++20 but with extensions turned off (I don't know what these do - will check). Ok so it seems to be a compiler problem.