# how to specify the return type in a requirement for a concept for types that contains a static constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

This problem is very simmilar to the one described in:
[C++ concept: Requiring a static variable to be present in a policy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608845/c-concept-requiring-a-static-variable-to-be-present-in-a-policy-class)
, but the solution does not work for me.
My example is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T1>
concept AConcept = requires(T1 a)
{
    // { a.typef }; // without requiring the return type it works.
    { a.typef } -> std::same_as<char>; // not working with char& either.
};

struct Aclass{
    static constexpr char typef='c';
    char getVal(){ return typef; };
};

char getVal( AConcept auto kk ){
    return kk.getVal();
};

int main(){
    Aclass u;
    char c = getVal( u );
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

and the compilation fails because the concept requirement is not satisfied.
(g++ 11.2.0, compiled with  `g++ -std=c++20 kk.cpp -o kk`)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T1>
concept AConcept = std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T1>().typef ), const char>;

struct Aclass{
    static constexpr char typef ='c';

    char getVal(){ return typef; };
};

char getVal( AConcept auto kk ){
    return kk.getVal();
};

int main(){
    Aclass u;
    char c = getVal( u );
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Or if you don't care about the l-value reference you could define the concept like this:

```
template<typename T1>
concept AConcept = requires(T1 a)
{
    { a.typef } -> std::same_as<const char&>;
};
```

Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires.

The type of the field access expression is `const char&` - it is the same as: `decltype((expression))`.

Have a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype
The important part here is the `(` and `)` around the entity which makes it an expression...

Comment: Thank you, I had already tried the std::is_same...::value approach, but I failed to see the need of declval. I still do not know why decltype( T1::typef ) is not valid inside the is_same_v template, and declval is neede.

Comment: Oh, decltype(T1::typef) would be valid, too. Even more valid, if you want to force a static field. see: https://godbolt.org/z/Wa5PErs6a
Can you show me the failing code?