Is there a more ergonomic way of defining function parameter requirements in C++20 concepts?
With C++20 concepts, I've started using them as a way to define templated class "interfaces", as they make for very nice compiler errors. However, I'm struggling a little to define them in an ergonomic, and readable way.
For example, let's say I want to make a concept IFoo that statically checks a class has the following three functions with the exact input/return types:
struct Foo {
    void bar(uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {}
    int32_t baz(int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {return 0;}
    void bax(char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {}
};

If this concept is defined correctly, then static_assert(IFoo<Foo>); would compile. The only way I can get this behavior in a "single" concept definition is as follows:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T ifoo, uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c, int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f, char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {
    {ifoo.bar(a, b, c)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    {ifoo.baz(d, e, f)} -> std::same_as<int32_t>;
    {ifoo.bax(g, h, i)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

This satisfies the requirement, however it's not particularly readable as you have to mentally transfer the (many) types from the requires() arguments to the function inputs to form an idea of what the function prototypes should look like if you implement this class. Another way to accomplish this is defining a different concept per function and chaining them like so:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo_bar = requires(T ifoo, uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {
    {ifoo.bar(a, b, c)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<typename T>
concept IFoo_baz = requires(T ifoo, int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {
    {ifoo.baz(d, e, f)} -> std::same_as<int32_t>;
};


template<typename T>
concept IFoo_bax = requires(T ifoo, char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {
    {ifoo.bax(g, h, i)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires { 
    requires IFoo_bar<T>;
    requires IFoo_baz<T>;
    requires IFoo_bax<T>;
};

However this creates a lot of boilerplate code which isn't ideal. What I really want (that doesn't compile) is the ability to nest requirement blocks like so:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T ifoo) {
    requires(uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {
        {ifoo.bar(a, b, c)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
    requires(int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {
        {ifoo.baz(d, e, f)} -> std::same_as<int32_t>;
    };
    requires(char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {
        {ifoo.bax(g, h, i)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
};

Am I missing something? Or are the avenues I've already explored the only way to accomplish what I'm after? Really am hoping I'm missing something in the docs that will make this a bit easier!

you dont need them {ifoo.bar(uint32_t{},uint16_t{},uint8_t{})} -> std::same_as<void>;, basically this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71614974/4117728

as a/d are the same type, you might get rid of one of them.

N.b. you don't test for exact parameter types, only that arguments of those types implicitly convert to those parameter types

@Caleth that's actually somewhat useful to keep in mind, it may feel like I'm trying to write a "function prototype" via a concept, but that is absolutely not what a concept is in reality.

@haydenridd: I feel like if you used actual meaningful parameter names, it'd be a lot more readable. a says nothing and has no meaning.

std::same_as<void> - that is generally an anti-pattern.  For non-void, you should do convertible_to, and for void you shouldn't care.  Someone creating a method with compatible arguments and compatible return values should satisfy your contract.  Concepts should check use, not implementation.

You don't need to name every single parameter in your requires clause.
struct Foo {
  void bar(int n) {}
};

template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T foo) {
  {foo.bar(0)} -> std::same_as<void>;
};


works perfectly fine. If you have a type whose values are a bit more complicated to construct you can just use declval
struct Foo {
  void bar(Unmentionable n) {}
};

template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T foo) {
  {foo.bar(std::declval<Unmentionable>())} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

the params in requires are all basically just shorthands for declval anyway, you don't need to write any at all:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires {
  {std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Unmentionable>())} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

However, if you really like the requires syntax a lot you can actually nest them as in your original question:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T ifoo) {
    requires requires(uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {
        {ifoo.bar(a, b, c)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
    requires requires(int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {
        {ifoo.baz(d, e, f)} -> std::same_as<int32_t>;
    };
    requires requires(char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {
        {ifoo.bax(g, h, i)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    };
};

You just had one requires too few (the goofy double requires comes because one introduces a nested requirement, and a requires expression is a possible thing to put there; hence requires requires.

Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. I like combining this with another comment about using the type constructors in the function call to indicate type rather than an input to the requires clause, and then using declval<> for more complex/user defined types.

@Cubic: "works perfectly fine" No, it doesn't. 0 is a null pointer constant. As such, a function which takes a pointer of any kind will satisfy that constraint.

@NicolBolas And? The question was about syntax, not about how to harden the requires clauses (which were already pretty loose in the example).

@Cubic Yes and as Nicol is pointing out, using 0 is a bad choice of syntax (because it makes the requirements completely unclear). If you want to just say pass an int, 1 is a lot better in that regard.

You might chaining them with &&:
template<typename T>
concept IFoo =
    requires(T ifoo, uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {
        {ifoo.bar(a, b, c)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    } &&
    requires(T ifoo, int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {
        {ifoo.baz(d, e, f)} -> std::same_as<int32_t>;
    } &&
    requires(T ifoo, char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {
        {ifoo.bax(g, h, i)} -> std::same_as<void>;
    };


Nice! Weirdly I tried doing this earlier but just must have messed up the syntax, this makes for something that is nice on the eyes!

Well, I do get that you want to avoid boilerplate code. You may also want to avoid 3rd-party libraries though I'm going to show you one (my own if you wish to use it - quite short for what it offers, effectively single-header only and fully documented here). It provides a full complement of easy-to-use templates for determining function traits such as parameter types, parameter count, return type, whether a non-static member function is "const", "volatile", etc. It therefore gives you the ability to really zero in on your task. Granted, you may wish to stick with your current techniques or perhaps find some hybrid you're happy with (a mixture of your own and the library's). The following example demos its capabilities however. Whether you think it's overkill for you particular needs is your call of course. As noted, you can also use the library's other templates to determine if the functions are "const", "volatile", "noexcept", non-varidiac (no "..." in the parameter list), etc., simply by adding these checks to the signature concepts below ("HasBarSignature", "HasBazSignature" and "HasBaxSignature"). Note that it may even be possible to condense this code but it's just my first quick crack at it (but still quite clean in spite of its lengthy appearance).
Sorry, no time to properly document the code but the library itself is thoroughly documented (see above link). Also note that it assumes no overloads of your functions exist or "IFoo" will return false (since the call to "&T::NAME" seen in the DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION macro can't disambiguate overloads, a limitation of the language itself - overcoming it not doable without casting to target the exact overload you're interested in but longer story). Anyway, I hope it helps.
Click here to run it.
// Standard C++ headers
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// See https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits
// Only header required from this library ...
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "TypeTraits.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Boiler plate macro you can stick in some generic
// header (will leave for you to figure out)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(NAME) \
    template <typename, typename = void> \
    struct HasMemberFunction_##NAME : std::false_type \
    { \
    }; \
    template <typename T> \
    struct HasMemberFunction_##NAME<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::NAME)>>> : std::true_type \
    { \
    }; \
    template <typename T> \
    inline constexpr bool HasMemberFunction_##NAME##_v = HasMemberFunction_##NAME<T>::value;

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implementation code for all your interface
// concepts ("IFoo" only in this example).
////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace Private
{
    namespace Concepts
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Packaging up the "IFoo" implementation in this
        // namespace. You can repeat this code for each of
        // your interfaces (customizing it for each one
        // accordingly)
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        namespace IFoo
        {
            ///////////////////
            // Function "bar"
            ///////////////////
            namespace Bar
            {
                DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(bar);

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // See these "StdExt" templates at
                // https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                template <typename T>
                concept HasBarSignature = StdExt::IsVoidReturnType_v<T> &&
                                          StdExt::ArgCount_v<T> == 3 &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 0>, uint32_t > &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 1>, uint16_t> &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 2>, uint8_t >;

                template <typename T>
                concept HasBar = HasMemberFunction_bar_v<T> &&
                                 HasBarSignature<decltype(&T::bar)>;
            }

            ///////////////////
            // Function "baz"
            ///////////////////        
            namespace Baz
            {
                DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(baz);

                template <typename T>
                concept HasBazSignature = std::is_same_v< StdExt::ReturnType_t<T>, int32_t > &&
                                          StdExt::ArgCount_v<T> == 3 &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 0>, int32_t > &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 1>, int16_t > &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 2>, uint8_t >;

                template <typename T>
                concept HasBaz = HasMemberFunction_baz_v<T> &&
                                 HasBazSignature<decltype(&T::baz)>;
            }

            ///////////////////
            // Function "bax"
            ///////////////////
            namespace Bax
            {
                DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(bax);

                template <typename T>
                concept HasBaxSignature = StdExt::IsVoidReturnType_v<T> &&
                                          StdExt::ArgCount_v<T> == 3 &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 0>, char > &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 1>, uint8_t * > &&
                                          std::is_same_v< StdExt::ArgType_t<T, 2>, uint32_t * >;

                template <typename T>
                concept HasBax = HasMemberFunction_bax_v<T> &&
                                 HasBaxSignature<decltype(&T::bax)>;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
concept IFoo = Private::Concepts::IFoo::Bar::HasBar<T> &&
               Private::Concepts::IFoo::Baz::HasBaz<T> &&
               Private::Concepts::IFoo::Bax::HasBax<T>;

// Sample struct from your post
struct Foo {
    void bar(uint32_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c) {}
    int32_t baz(int32_t d, int16_t e, uint8_t f) {return 0;}
    void bax(char g, uint8_t *h, uint32_t *i) {}
};

int main()
{
    // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IFoo<Foo>;

    return 0;
}

